# Python Пропускает следующие совпадения Шифрование

Tags: python

Есть код который шифрует фамилию, но если есть несколько одинаковых букв то код пропускает их, не могу найти в чем проблема

```
a = str(input('Введите Фамилию: '))
a = a.lower()
alph = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
name = {}
for i in a:
    name.update({i:alph.find(i)+1})
for letter, key in name.items():
   print ('Буква: {}, Код: {}, Шифрограмма: {}'.format(letter, key, key**5 % 91))
print (a)
```

Comment: а в чем проблема? вы удивляетесь, что в словаре только уникальные ключи?

Comment: Точно, а как это можно решить тогда?

Comment: скажите какая именно изначально стояла задача, тогда можно понять что именно нужно сделать

Comment: Шифровать фамилию по ключу key**5 % 91

Comment: Пока сделал это, пока хватает: if i in name:
        i += "!"

Comment: `key**5 % 91` а что такое `key`? код буквы, индекс буквы с словаре?

Comment: Номер буквы в алфавите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял задачу
Вам требуется вот это произвести?

```
a = 'пушкин'
alph = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
print(*[(alph.index(i)**5 % 91) for i in a]) # выведется 74 76 51 72 81 14
```

т.е. для каждой буквы получаем ее индекс, для индекса вычисляет `i**5 % 91`

дальше в буквы перевести нельзя поскольку `i**5 % 91` предполагает 91 символ, а в словаре 33 буквы или нужен какой-то расширенный словарь, содержащий 91 символ

или нужно это?

```
a = 'пушкин'
alph = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
encoded = ''.join(alph[alph.index(i)**5 % len(alph)] for i in a)

print(encoded) # выведется бцбклц
```